# How to update Poetry's lock file without upgrading dependencies?

Tags: python, python-poetry

After adding a `[tool.poetry.extras]` section to `pyproject.toml`, Poetry displays the following warning, for example on install:

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in pyproject.toml. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.

That's fine, but if I run `poetry update` it upgrades my dependencies, which is not what I want at this time. If I run `poetry lock` instead, it still upgrades dependencies.

Sorry for not providing a reproducible example, it's quite tricky to generate a poetry.lock file with outdated dependencies. My existing one is too large for posting here.

**Update**: Opened [sdispater/poetry#1614](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry/issues/1614) for this issue

Comment: I solved it with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62040725/9247792

Answer (score 162, accepted):

In v1, poetry defaults to updating dependencies when recreating the lockfile.

There is a specific option for the `lock` command that prevents this:

```
poetry lock --no-update
```

This makes it possible to remove a dependency from `pyproject.toml` and update the lock file without upgrading dependencies.

Note that this flag is only available since 1.1.2 (or earlier?) and that the behavior [will be changed in v2.0](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3248), because the maintainers agree that the tool should not perform updates unless explicitly asked to.

Comment: To all readers: In case poetry v2 is released and the behavior has changed, please feel free to edit/update this post!

Answer (score 15):

There does not currently (as of version `1.0.0b6`) seem to be any Poetry command which updates the lock file without also upgrading dependencies.

However, if your project has some up-to-date dependency `foo`, you can work around this limitation by invoking the following command:

```
poetry update foo
```

This will leave `foo` at the current version (because it is already at the latest version), and also won't touch any other dependencies. But it will synchronize the lock file with any changes to `pyproject.toml`.

In my own case, this command added the `[extras]` section to the lock file and updated the metadata content hash, without touching anything else. The lock file was now up-to-date and the warning disappeared.

**Update:**

A better workaround is to add and remove a package outside of the dependency tree, such as [insecure-package](https://pypi.org/project/insecure-package/):

```
poetry add insecure-package && poetry remove insecure-package
```

One reason why this is better is that with `poetry update` you need to pass exactly the same options that you originally used. More details on the GitHub issue mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why `poetry lock` is updating. The [documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#lock) does not mention that it updates the dependencies. This worked for me to remove the warning in my log outputs.

Comment: Your answer is now outdated, there is a `--no-update` option.

Comment: Here is the latest docs, "By default, this will lock all dependencies to the latest available compatible versions. To only refresh the lock file, use the --no-update option. This command is also available as a pre-commit hook. See pre-commit hooks for more information."