# Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, python-poetry

When I am using a poetry command with Python 3.7, in my case:

```
poetry export -f requirements.txt
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in pyproject.toml. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
```

So far clear, but if I run poetry update it upgrades my dependencies, which is not what I want at this time for my project. If I run poetry lock instead, it still upgrades dependencies.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1614) in Poetry.

The issue is resolved, use: `poetry lock --no-update`.

### **Old answer:**

There is a current workaround with the following commands:

```
poetry add pathlib2
poetry remove pathlib2
```

Where pathlib2 is *any* library you **don't already depend on** and that has no dependencies on it's own, hence pathlib2.

Using these commands will rewrite the lockfile hashes and resolve the file conflict without upgrading any of the other packages used in the project.

Comment: I'm still getting this error, even after adding and removing packages (they DO trigger a regeneration of the lockfile, just still have the error even with the new lockfile)

Comment: If that's an option, remove the `poetry.lock` file an do a fresh install @SamJett

Comment: Poetry now has a `poetry lock --no-update` command that leads to the same result. It's mentionned in the linked Github issue, you might want to update your answer @marcuse

Comment: To make it a bit easier for people working in Windows: You probably need to find the poetry executable. At least for my project, it's like:  `.\.poetry\bin\poetry.exe lock --no-update`

Answer (score 0):

The following change in the build.sh file fixes this issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# exit on error
set -o errexit

echo "Installing the latest version of poetry..."

pip install --upgrade pip

pip install poetry==1.2.0

rm poetry.lock

poetry lock

python -m poetry install
```

Source: https://community.render.com/t/update-poetry-to-1-2-0/7957/11

Answer (score -7):

Try the command

poetry install

Comment: Why? How does this command solve the problem and why is this better than the other answer?